# SoapUI Groovy - Extract Child Node using json slurper object filter

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

Snippet From Json Response -

```
[
    {
      "id": "ada2ac5d-57f1-4624-b35a-4fd34ada9e56",
      "userId": "userid",
      "firstName": "firstname",
      "lastName": "lastname",
      "dateAdded": "2018-07-06T04:19:21.57",
      "dateOfChange": "2018-07-06T04:19:22.14",
      "lastAction": "Updated",
   },
      {
      "id": "2f395120-5440-4770-8a2e-16a77aa69c1e",
      "userId": "userid",
      "firstName": "firstname",
      "lastName": "lastname",
      "dateAdded": "2018-07-06T04:19:21.57",
      "dateOfChange": "2018-07-06T04:19:21.99",
      "lastAction": "Updated",
   },
      {
      "id": "7aaa6b11-0f43-414b-a999-b03114392c21",
      "userId": "userid",
      "firstName": "firstname",
      "lastName": "lastname",
      "dateAdded": "2018-07-06T04:19:21.693",
      "dateOfChange": "2018-07-06T04:19:21.743",
      "lastAction": "Added",
   },
]
```

======================

I would like to capture'lastAction' value based on id match.

I have tried following -

```
responseContent = testStepp.getPropertyValue("response") //getting response
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseContent)

log.info "last action : : "

object.('$.[?(@.id=="ada2ac5d-57f1-4624-b35a-4fd34ada9e56")].lastAction')
```

Result -

last action : : [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Answer (score 1):

Try using Groovy's `.find()` function:

```
object.find { it.id == 'ada2ac5d-57f1-4624-b35a-4fd34ada9e56' }.lastAction
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object.find{it.id=="7aaa6b11-0f43-414b-a999-b03114392c21"}?.lastAction
```